# global variable is not seen by functions inside script tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I declared a variable as global inside

> var orid ;

then I used get function inside query from Parse.com  ((Here "orid" doesn't save the info ))

```
    query.get("ZL8OcUjnJX", {
        success: function(object) {
    orid = object.get("OrderId");
        },

        error: function(object, error) {
        // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
        }
        });
```

Then I used This function in order to use it inside html tag 
(( it shows undefined doent show the data from previous function))

```
    function showinfo(){
        document.write(orid);}
```

and I called it inside the html tag to print it in the page

```
    <td id="intro"> 
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
          showinfo();
   </script> 
  </td>
```

The problem is when I wanna this information to appear in webpage it doesn't do. Also, when I tried

> document.write(orid);

inside function "get" it overwrite the page at all

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.  Instead, use the DOM APIs inside the callback.

Comment: Have a look at [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for an explanation of the problem and possible solutions. Moving the function call inside the `get` success callback is correct, just don't use `document.write`.

Comment: Also, `document.write` is likely going to obliterate everything you have anyway...

Comment: I took a look at the link you for AJAX but i did not use before the AJAX so I will need a time to learn it ,, is there any simple way to print data instead of using "document.write" @FelixK

Comment: You can use `console.log`. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).